# Tag 'h1' not closed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am a Winforms guy and learning ASP.Net. Was learning MVC 4 with Razor from a tutorial. Here is my code.

```
@using MVC_Employee.Models;
@{
    var model = new Employee()
        {
            Name = "Rapsy Tree",
            Department = "Development",
            JoinTime = DateTime.Now,
        };
}

<div>
    <h1>@model.Name</h1> // Getting error in typing Name and also VS intellisense not populating this.
</div>
```

**Errors**

Compile Time Error: `Tag 'h1' not closed`

Runtime Error:

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1031: Type expected

```
 Source Error:

Line 38:      Line 39:      Line 40:     public class
_Page_Views_employee_employee_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<.Title</h1>> { Line 41:          Line 42:
#line hidden
```

Well I know this is against MVC rules to use Model in View but I was just trying to learn razor syntax. Can anybody help me to understand the error please? Thanks.

Comment: looks like a magic... I can just recomend you to set Layout = null; after model initialization. May be its another tag in masterpage :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution & I am not sure how to answer this. I have edited my question to reflect the exact problem. All this time I was using `model` as my variable name. I changed it to `employee` and everything worked. Stupid but true and also cant understand much about it.

This is the final working code

```
@using MVC_Employee.Models;
@{
    var employee = new Employee()
        {
            Name = "Rapsy Tree",
            Department = "Development",
            JoinTime = DateTime.Now,
        };
}

<div>
    <h1>@employee.Name</h1> // Getting error in typing Name and also VS intellisense not populating this.
</div>
```

Comment: `model` is the Razor keyword to access the page model in a strongly-typed view; I guess it must conflict when you use it for something else.

Comment: Yes. I figured it out. However, thanks for further clarification :)

Answer (score 3):

Try adding space:

```
<h1> @employee.Name </h1>
```

**[Take a look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694814/element-not-closed-error-after-upgrading-from-mvc3-to-mvc4)**

Comment: +1...even if it did not help in this problem you provided a useful link

Answer (score 3):

### **Replicated your problem.**

When you reference a View Model to make your View as *Strongly Type*, you mentioned in the model like below

```
@model Practise.Areas.MyPractise.Models.Dropdown
@{
    var mod = new Practise.Areas.MyPractise.Models.Dropdown();
}

<div>
    <h1> @mod.YourPropertyName </h1> populating this.
</div>
```

**If you pay attention to the above code, I declared a variable called mod instead of model**

*This is important to understand. Basically **MVC** uses model as keyword to reference the View as Strongly type and you used the same keyword for your variable. This was the actual problem*

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the semicolon in your `@using` line.